# Share file/text with other apps and successful callback in flutter

Tags: file, flutter, dart, share, intentservice

**is there way to get callback is file is shared successfully in flutter with share?**

I have to make sure that file is shared/uploaded to other apps(whatsapp/gmail/other). i am sharing file in [flutter_share](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_share) plugin in flutter. then complete action dialog box opens to choose an app, after returning to app screen, i need to get callback/flag to ensure fill is shared in other apps successfully.

---

**steps can be taken:**

- get callback from share
- checking callback in onresume of app
- showing success / failure message.

---

will solution work for both platforms android n ios?

Thanks in advance. Any solutions to this one.

Comment: Did you already find a solution? Currently also having this problem...

Comment: yes still having problem. can't detect exaclty if item is shared / not

Answer (score 0):

it looks like there is still no solution: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/67637